# Python Regex: OR statement does not work in regex module

Tags: python, regex

Hi I want apply the following expression to check substitutions,  insertions,  deletion counts. However the OR statement seems like it does not work. Regex check only the first statement in the paranthesis.
For example:

```
correct_string = "20181201"
regex_pattern = r"((20[0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])){e}"
regex.fullmatch(regex_pattern, correct_string)
```

Output:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='20181201', fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)>
```

It says there is one substitution because of the 5th digit however if in the OR statement it exist

Another example:

```
correct_string = "20180201"
regex_pattern = r"((20[0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])){e}"
regex.fullmatch(regex_pattern, correct_string)
```

Output:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='20180201'>
```

In this case it says there are no substitutions which is correct according to first statement in the OR.

How can I solve this. Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected result here?

Comment: both outputs should look like this: <regex.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='20180201'>

Comment: Yeah, use `regex.ENHANCEMATCH`

Comment: Looks like the regex engine would rather  get fuzzy on an alternate than try the next alternate in the regex. Why do you need fuzzy matching and could you turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`regex.ENHANCEMATCH`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

> By default, fuzzy matching searches for the first match that meets the given constraints. The `ENHANCEMATCH` flag will cause it to attempt to improve the fit (i.e. reduce the number of errors) of the match that it has found.

Python demo:

```
import regex
correct_string = "20181201"
regex_pattern = r"((20[0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])){e}"
print(regex.fullmatch(regex_pattern, correct_string, regex.ENHANCEMATCH))
// => <regex.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='20181201'>
```

See the [online Python demo](https://rextester.com/PATU59815).